# L'expression « sacré bleu » a-t-elle vraiment existé dans la langue française?

Tags: expressions, histoire, jurons

Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un utiliser l'expression « sacré bleu ». A-t-elle vraiment existé autrefois ?

Comment: Autrefois ? L'expression existe encore dans la littérature québecoise qui ne date pas de si longtemps que ça.

Comment: Justement, tout le monde sait que le québecois c'est le français d'autrefois :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut trouver des exemples de l'utilisation de *sacrebleu* via [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sacrebleu%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr).

Le [ngram correspondant](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=sacrebleu,sacr%C3%A9bleu,sacre%20bleu,sacr%C3%A9%20bleu&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3) est aussi très instructif : il ne trouve **que** *sacrebleu*, et pas *sacré bleu* (+1 pour Borror0). On voit aussi que l'usage de *sacrebleu* décline progressivement.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, ainsi que « sacrebleu » sans accent. On peut trouver plusieurs exemples [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sacrebleu).

Comment: Je ne vois pas de preuve pour « sacré bleu ». Sacrebleu, c'est très commun - du moins au Québec - mais je suis pas mal sûr que « sacré bleu » est incorrect.

Comment: @Borror0 : Selon [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrebleu), ça a éxisté. Malheureusement la référence citée n'est pas sur Internet.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu "sacré bleu" dans la littérature (encore moins entendu), mais "sacrebleu" est extrêmement courant dans le français parler jusqu'au début du XXè siècle au moins.

Answer (score 3):

L'entrée wikipedia anglaise pour [Sacrebleu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrebleu) nous éclaire sur le fait que "sacré bleu" viendrait non pas de "sacre dieu", mais bien de bleu, la couleur de Marie, bien que ce soit la première fois que je rencontre cette explication.